# pandas dataFrame with datetime64[ns] as Index with microsecond precision

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `dataFrame` with `datetime64[ns]` as Index. Since the data is of microsecond precision, I want to copy this date to another `dataFrame` with second or minute level precision so that I can easily plot/visualize it. Any idea how to do this? Also can this be done without copying the data to another `dataFrame`?

```
                           Name  Fruit
2016-11-03 21:20:15.555222 John  Apple
2016-11-03 21:20:15.555266 John  Kiwi
2016-11-03 21:20:15.555292 Mary  Apple
2016-11-03 21:20:16.595222 Peter Apple
2016-11-03 21:20:16.599222 Peter Orange
2016-11-03 21:20:16.655222 John  Apple
2016-11-03 21:20:17.659222 John  Apple
2016-11-03 21:20:17.660222 John  Apple

After the Change i wan't :
                           Name  Fruit
2016-11-03 21:20:15.555222 John  Apple
2016-11-03 21:20:16.595222 Peter Apple
2016-11-03 21:20:17.659222 John  Apple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try resampling and using last value of the second.

```
df.resample(rule='1S').last()
```